# Tools to debug Ruby on Rails slow performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built a ruby on rails application. Problem is when I click on button in the webpage, the load time is very slow. I'm not able to find the root cause of why my page time is slow.

One thing I noticed is After I clicked the button, Its taking time to even change URL path on browser, So I assume issue is there .I would like to get an idea on how I can debug the issue.

sorry if question is too generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it on Linux, you can try to use tool `strace` or sometimes `ltrace`. But the easiest way is to run the code from the command-line, for example:

`strace -fttt ruby website.rb`

If you can't run it from command line, you can attach to the process which is already running or to parent process:

`strace -tttf -p <pid of your web ruby process server>`

You can also use tool called `rbtrace`

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using Meta-Request.

By utilizing this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/railspanel/gjpfobpafnhjhbajcjgccbbdofdckggg?hl=en-US) and this [gem](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel/tree/master/meta_request) you can track down any issues that might be degrading performance in your app (i.e inefficient db queries)